# How to join EF query with dictionary

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, dictionary, linq-to-entities

In global.asax defined and filled Dictionary

```
public static Dictionary<Guid, string> GlobalUserDictionary;
```

In controller some logics load data from db via EF DbContext

```
var db = new DbModel();

var visits = db.Visits.Select(d => new
{
    Id = d.Id,
    UserId = d.UserId,
    User = MvcApplication.GlobalUserDictionary[d.UserId]
});
```

but controller throw exception:

> System.NotSupportedException: LINQ to Entities does not recognize
>   the method 'System.String get_Item(System.Guid)' method, and this
>   method cannot be translated into a store expression.

How to join dbcontext model with external data resourse like Dictionary or something similar to it?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

To use the dictionary inside the `Select` you need to work with `Linq to Object` instead `Linq to Entities`. [`AsEnumerable`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb335435(v=vs.110).aspx) extension method is going to help you to do that:

```
    var visits = db.Visits.AsEnumerable().Select(d => new
    {
        Id = d.Id,
        UserId = d.UserId,
        User = MvcApplication.GlobalUserDictionary[d.UserId];
    });
```

### Update

It's true is not a good idea call `AsEnumerable`  without filtering your data first, but after doing that, it could be a good idea call it:

```
var visits = db.Visits.Select(d => new
{
    d.Id,
    d.UserId
})
.AsEnumerable()
.Select(d => new
{
    Id = d.Id,
    UserId = d.UserId,
    User = MvcApplication.GlobalUserDictionary[d.UserId]
});
```

The advantage of using `AsEnumerable` instead `ToList` is that `AsEnumerable` does not execute the query until you consult the data, it preserves deferred execution.

Comment: doesn't `d.UserId` come from the lambda within the query?

Comment: But how i can use D outside of query? D not exist in current context.

Comment: it's true, my mistake guys, I have updated my answer

Comment: No worries. The first line is also unnecessary.

Comment: If `Visits` has 20 columns, your code will retrieve 18 unnecessary columns of data. That could be a rather significant performance issue.

Comment: In my experience, `.Join()` is faster than `.Select()` when every entry is going to retrieve an item from a dictionary, so I'd use that as the last method in the chain instead.  It also won't throw an exception if a key can't be found, but it will drop those entries from `Visits` out.

Comment: @afrazier do you have a benchmark to back up your claim?

Comment: @Stijn: Not immediately handy, but I have benchmarked it before and found a significant difference as the source data grew.  I'll try to write up something reproducible later tonight.

Answer (score 4):

First select the data from the DB you need, then do a select again to make your full model. Don't use `AsEnumerable()` on the entire `DbSet` because you'd retrieve columns that you don't need.

```
var visits = db.Visits.Select(d => new
{
    d.Id,
    d.UserId
})
.ToList()
.Select(d => new
{
    Id = d.Id,
    UserId = d.UserId,
    User = MvcApplication.GlobalUserDictionary[d.UserId]
});
```